# Ruby: get string between strings?

Tags: ruby

I want to get the `3stars` from 
`http://images.penguinmagic.com/images/3stars.gif`
How can I do it? Can it be done elegantly without using `regex`?

I can do it using `split` 2 times, but think this is quite bad code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One easy option is :

```
url = "http://images.penguinmagic.com/images/3stars.gif"
File.basename(url, File.extname(url)) # => "3stars"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use rpartition:

```
url.rpartition('.')[0].rpartition('/')[2]
```

But I don't see that much of a problem with the 'bad code' of doing two splits or even using regex, unless you're uncomfortable with regexp in general, in which case this would be a good chance to start learning about them.